Playing YouTube Video Audio Only in a React Native Expo Application
I'm aiming to implement a feature in my React Native Expo application where I can play only the audio from a YouTube video, similar to a music app. Currently, I'm encountering issues with integrating audio playback libraries within Expo. I've explored react-native-sound, but it seems to have compatibility issues with Expo. Additionally, react-native-track-player hasn't met my requirements satisfactorily.
What alternative approaches or libraries can I utilize to achieve this functionality effectively within the constraints of Expo? Any insights or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.
